# Enzyme React button component not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, enzyme, mount

I am trying to check if button exists and then simulate a click on it.
But my button component is not found. returns length 0.
Where am i going wrong?

```
const selectAll = (props:Props) => (
  <div className="selectall">
    <Button
      className="selectall"
      onClick={props.setBoard}
    />
  </div>
);
```

test

```
  When(/^select all button is clicked$/, function () {
    const mySpy = new MySpy();
    const mockCallBack = mySpy.fn();

    const button = enzyme.mount(React.createElement(Button, { onClick: mockCallBack }));
    const childBtn = button.find('.selectall');
    console.log("select button found ??? ==== " + childBtn.exists());  // false
  });
```

Comment: Can't reproduce it. It works fine.